# World IPv6 day 2014

Tags: code-golf, string, networking

To mark the anniversary of [World IPv6 day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_IPv6_Day_and_World_IPv6_Launch_Day), the Internet Society has published a campaign to [Turn Off IPv4 on 6 June 2014 for One Day](http://www.internetsociety.org/deploy360/blog/2013/12/campaign-turn-off-ipv4-on-6-june-2014-for-one-day/).

---

IPv6 addresses may be represented in their long form as eight colon-separated 16-bit hex values.  Depending on the address, they may also be shortened as described in item 2 of [section 2.2 *Text Representation of Addresses* of RFC 3513](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3513#section-2.2):

> In order to make writing addresses containing zero bits easier a special syntax is available to compress the zeros.  The use of "::" indicates one or more groups of 16 bits of zeros.  The "::" can only appear once in an address.  The "::" can also be used to compress leading or trailing zeros in an address.

- Entries to this challenge will be programs that accept exactly one IPv6 address formatted in either the long or shortened format, and will display the same address in **both** the long and short formats, in that order.
- The input may come from command-line arguments, STDIN, or any other input source that suits your choice of language.
- Libraries or utilities specifically for parsing IPv6 addresses are banned (e.g. [inet_{ntop,pton}()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/inet_ntop.html)).
- If the input address is invalid, the output will be empty (or some suitable error message **indicating the address is invalid** is given)
- In cases where `::` shortening occurs, only one shortening operation may happen for a given address.  If there are more than one potential shortening operations for a given address, the operation that gives the overall shortest address must be used.  If there is a tie in this regard, the first operation will be used.  This is illustrated in the examples below.
- [Standard loopholes to be avoided](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/standard-loopholes-which-are-no-longer-funny)

Examples:

```
Input                         Output

1080:0:0:0:8:800:200C:417A    1080:0:0:0:8:800:200C:417A
                              1080::8:800:200C:417A

FF01::101                     FF01:0:0:0:0:0:0:101
                              FF01::101

0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1               0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
                              ::1

::                            0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0
                              ::

1:0:0:2:0:0:0:3               1:0:0:2:0:0:0:3
                              1:0:0:2::3

1:0:0:8:8:0:0:3               1:0:0:8:8:0:0:3
                              1::8:8:0:0:3

1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8               1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8
                              1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8

ABCD:1234                     <Invalid address format - no output>

ABCDE::1234                   <Invalid address format - no output>

1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9             <Invalid address format - no output>

:::1                          <Invalid address format - no output>

codegolf puzzle               <Invalid address format - no output>
```

This is [codegolf](/questions/tagged/codegolf), so the shortest answer in bytes on June 6th 2014 will be accepted as the winner.

Comment: Say the input is `1:0:0:2:2::3`. Would the shortened output be identical to that or `1::2:2:0:0:3`? Same for non-optimally shortened input.

Comment: @m.buettner In this case, I'll let you pick either.

Comment: Is `1::2:0:0:0:3` a possible input?

Comment: @ace In accordance with the [late great Jon Postel's Robustness principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle), yes.

Comment: I think this is the only way anyone's ever going to get me to learn ipv6. +1

Comment: Can we just uncontrollably crash on malformed input?

Comment: @NickT Only if the result of the crash is no output or a suitable error message about the invalid address format.  Otherwise, no ;-)

Comment: What should the short form second line output be for `1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8`? There is no legal place to put `::`.

Comment: @MtnViewMark If a long-form address cannot be shortened, then the long and short forms are identical.

Comment: Should we support IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses like `::ffff:74.125.136.101`? Should we support link-local addresses like `fe80::1%eth0`?

Comment: @Vi. No, don't bother with ipv4-in-ipv6 formats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### JavaScript (ES6) - <strike>198</strike>, <strike>183</strike>, <strike>180</strike>, <strike>188</strike>, 187 bytes

```
f=s=>/^(:[\da-f]{1,4}){8}$/i.test(':'+(s=s[r='replace'](d='::',':0'.repeat((n=8-s.split(/:+/).length%9)||1)+':')[r](/^:0|0:$/g,n?'0:0':0)))&&[s,s[r](/(\b0(:0)*)(?!.*\1:0)/,d)[r](/::+/,d)]
```

And, a bit longer, interactive version with some pop-ups (203 bytes):

```
/^(:[\da-f]{1,4}){8}$/i.test(':'+(s=(s=prompt())[r='replace'](d='::',':0'.repeat((n=8-s.split(/:+/).length%9)||1)+':')[r](/^:0|0:$/g,n?'0:0':0)))&&alert(s+'\n'+s[r](/(\b0(:0)*)(?!.*\1:0)/,d)[r](/::+/,d))
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
function ipv6(str) {
    "use strict";
    var zeros = 8 - str.split(/:+/).length % 9

        ,longIP = str
            .replace('::', ':0'.repeat(zeros || 1) + ':')
            .replace(/^:0|0:$/g, zeros ? '0:0' : '0')

        ,shortIP = longIP
            .replace(/(\b0(:0)*)(?!.*\1:0)/,':')
            .replace(/::+/,'::');

    return /^(:[\da-f]{1,4}){8}$/i.test(':'+longIP) && [longIP, shortIP];
}
```

**Explanation:**

To calculate the long version of the IPv6 address:

`8 - str.split(/:+/).length % 9` - calculate how many zeros we need to insert. They are 8 - the number of the hex values. Here % 9 is a guard so it will never be a negative number.

`replace('::', ':0'.repeat(zeros || 1) + ':')` - replace the "::" with colon separated zeros. If there are no zeros to add it still adds one so the address won't be valid in the end

`replace(/^:0|0:$/g, zeros ? '0:0' : '0')` - this deals with the special case when the address starts or ends with "::" as the `split` function adds 1 to the number of hex values (::1 -> ["", "1"])

That's it! Now let's calculate the short form:

`replace(/(\b0(:0)*)(?!.*\1:0)/,':')` - replace longest row of zeros with colon(s) (It doesn't matter how many).

`replace(/::+/,'::')` - remove the extra colons if any

`return /^(:[\da-f]{1,4}){8}$/i.test(':'+longIP) && [longIP, shortIP];` - test if the long version is valid IPv6 and return both versions or `false` if the test fails.

**Tests in Firefox:**

```
>>> f('1080:0:0:0:8:800:200C:417A')
["1080:0:0:0:8:800:200C:417A", "1080::8:800:200C:417A"]
>>> f('FF01::101')
["FF01:0:0:0:0:0:0:101", "FF01::101"]
>>> f('0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1')
["0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1", "::1"]
>>> f('::')
["0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0", "::"]
>>> f('1:0:0:2:0:0:0:3')
["1:0:0:2:0:0:0:3", "1:0:0:2::3"]
>>> f('1:0:0:8:8:0:0:3')
["1:0:0:8:8:0:0:3", "1::8:8:0:0:3"]
>>> f('1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8')
["1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8", "1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8"]
>>> f('ABCD:1234')
false
>>> f('ABCDE::1234')
false
>>> f('1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9')
false
>>> f(':::1')
false
>>> f('1:2:3:4::a:b:c:d')
false
>>> f('codegolf puzzle')
false
```

Comment: So much better than mine! Just needs some correction to handle input like this ::1:, :1::

Comment: This one accepted the invalid `1:2:3:4::a:b:c:d`

Answer (score 6):

## Javascript (E6) 246 <s>305 284 292 319</s>

**Heavily revised**
Special case for :: specifically handled, compress phase avoids the for loop (but not very shorter indeed)
<s>I'm sure that the final compress phase can be made shorter. Not now anyway</s>

```
F=i=>(c=':',d=c+c,z=':0'.repeat(9-i.split(c,9).length)+c,i=i==d?0+z+0:i[R='replace'](/^::/,0+z)[R](/::$/,z+0)[R](d,z>c?z:d),/^(:[\da-f]{1,4}){8}:$/i.test(k=c+i+c)&&[i,k[R]((k.match(/:(0:)+/g)||[]).sort().pop(),d)[R](/^:([^:])|([^:]):$/g,'$1$2')])
```

Thanks to [nderscore](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20160/nderscore)

**As a program**

Input and output using js popup, basically: `p=prompt,p(F(p()))`
Rewriting with popup and without the function definition, the char count should be under 260

**Ungolfed** 
and commented a bit

```
F = i => (
  c = ':',
  d = c+c,
  z = ':0'.repeat(9-i.split(c,9).length) + c, 
  i = i == d ? 0+z+0 /* special case '::' */
    : i.replace(/^::/,0+z) /* special case '::...' */
       .replace(/::$/,z+0) /* special case '...::' */
       .replace(d, z > c ? z : d), /* here, if z==c, not valid: too much colons */
  /^(:[\da-f]{1,4}){8}:$/i.test(k = c+i+c) /* Check if valid */
  && [
   i, 
   k.replace((k.match(/:(0:)+/g)||[]).sort().pop(),d) /* find longest 0: sequence and replace it */
    .replace(/^:([^:])|([^:]):$/g,'$1$2') /* cut leading and trailing colons */
  ]
)
```

**Test**
In console

```
i=['1080:0:0:0:8:800:200C:417A'
, '::1:2:3:4:5:6:7', '1:2:3:4:5:6:7::'
, '1:2:3:4::5:6:7:8'
, ':1:2:3:4:5:6:7', '1:2:3:4:5:6:7:'
, 'FF01::101', '0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1'
, '::', '1::', '::1', ':::1', '1:::'
, '1:0:0:2:0:0:0:3', '1:0:0:0:2:0:0:3', '1::8:0:0:0:3'
, '1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8'
, 'ABCD:1234', 'ABCDE::1234', ':::', '::::::::::'
, '1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9', '::::1', 'codegolf puzzle'];
i.map(x=>x+' => '+F(x)).join('\n')
```

**Test output**

```
"1080:0:0:0:8:800:200C:417A => 1080:0:0:0:8:800:200C:417A,1080::8:800:200C:417A
::1:2:3:4:5:6:7 => 0:1:2:3:4:5:6:7,::1:2:3:4:5:6:7
1:2:3:4:5:6:7:: => 1:2:3:4:5:6:7:0,1:2:3:4:5:6:7::
1:2:3:4::5:6:7:8 => false
:1:2:3:4:5:6:7 => false
1:2:3:4:5:6:7: => false
FF01::101 => FF01:0:0:0:0:0:0:101,FF01::101
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 => 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1,::1
:: => 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,::
1:: => 1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,1::
::1 => 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1,::1
:::1 => false
1::: => false
1:0:0:2:0:0:0:3 => 1:0:0:2:0:0:0:3,1:0:0:2::3
1:0:0:0:2:0:0:3 => 1:0:0:0:2:0:0:3,1::2:0:0:3
1::8:0:0:0:3 => 1:0:0:8:0:0:0:3,1:0:0:8::3
1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8 => 1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8,1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8
ABCD:1234 => false
ABCDE::1234 => false
::: => false
:::::::::: => false
1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9 => false
::::1 => false
codegolf puzzle => false"
```

Comment: I'd rather a program than a function. I don't know javascript well enough to know if this is possible.

Comment: @nderscore Oops - typo.  Corrected in a new comment.

Comment: It could be made into a program by taking input from `prompt()`. Here are some optimizations that bring it down to 290: http://pastie.org/private/3ccpinzqrvvliu9nkccyg

Comment: @nderscore: thx, the 1st replace does not work for input = '::', great work anyway!

Comment: @edc65 I found a fix for that replace :) http://pastie.org/private/kee0sdvjez0vfcmlvaxu8q

Comment: Actually, that might not work. Seems it fails for this invalid address: `:1:2:3:4:5:6:7` :(

Comment: @nderscore problem with my original code too. Now I reached 284 but still can't compete against perl :(

Comment: This one rejected the valid addresses `::2:3:4:a:b:c:d` and `1:2:3:4:a:b:c::`

Answer (score 4):

## Perl - 204 <s>176 190 191 197</s>

(202 chars + 2 for `-p` flag)

```
$_=uc;(9-split/:/)||/^:|:$/||last;s/^::/0::/;s/::$/::0/;s|::|':0'x(9-split/:/).':'|e;/::|^:|:$|\w{5}|[^A-F0-:].*\n/||(8-split/:/)and last;s/\b0*(?!\b)//g;print;s/\b((0:)*0)\b(?!.*\1:0\b)/::/;s/::::?/::/
```

#### Example:

```sh
$ perl -p ipv6.pl <<< 1:0:2:0::3
1:0:2:0:0:0:0:3
1:0:2::3
$ perl -p ipv6.pl <<< somethinginvalid
$ perl -p ipv6.pl <<< 1:2:0:4:0:6::8
1:2:0:4:0:6:0:8
1:2::4:0:6:0:8
```

#### Explanation:

```
# -p reads a line from stdin and stores in $_
#
# Convert to uppercase
$_ = uc;

# Detect the annoying case @kernigh pointed out
(9 - split /:/) || /^:|:$/ || last;

# Fix :: hanging on the beginning or the end of the string
s/^::/0::/;
s/::$/::0/;

# Replace :: with the appropriate number of 0 groups
s|::|':0' x (9 - split /:/) . ':'|e;

# Silently exit if found an extra ::, a hanging :, a 5-char group, an invalid
# character, or there's not 8 groups
/::|^:|:$|\w{5}|[^A-F0-:].*\n/ || (8 - split /:/) and last;

# Remove leading zeros from groups
s/\b0*(?!\b)//g;

# Output the ungolfed form
print;

# Find the longest sequence of 0 groups (a sequence not followed by something
# and a longer sequence) and replace with ::
# This doesn't replace the colons around the sequence because those are optional
# thus we are left with 4 or 3 colons in a row
s/\b((0:)*0)\b(?!.*\1:0\b)/::/;

# Fix the colons after previous transformation
s/::::?/::/

# -p then prints the golfed form of the address
```

Comment: *"Died at ipv6.pl line 1, <> line 1"*.  This was asked about in the question comments.  If there is a message, it must be clear that it is because of an invalid message.  I tried to clarify that in the question.  Otherwise looks good!

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Changed `die` to a silent exit.

Comment: A bug? This program accepts the invalid address `1:2:3:4::a:b:c:d`. This is an annoying special case, because most eight-colon addresses are invalid, but `::2:3:4:a:b:c:d` and `1:2:3:4:a:b:c::` are both valid.

Answer (score 3):

## sed, 276

I have 275 bytes in ipshorten.sed, plus 1 byte for the `-r` switch in `sed -rf` to use extended regular expressions. I used OpenBSD [sed(1)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sed&sektion=1&manpath=OpenBSD%20Current&arch=i386&format=html).

**Usage:** `echo ::2:3:4:a:b:c:d | sed -rf ipshorten.sed`

```
s/^/:/
/^(:[0-9A-Fa-f]{0,4})*$/!d
s/:0*([^:])/:\1/g
s/://
s/::/:=/
s/(.:=)(.)/\10:\2/
s/^:=/0&/
s/=$/&0/
:E
/(.*:){7}/!{/=/!d
s//=0:/
bE
}
s/=//
/^:|::|:$|(.*:){8}/d
p
s/.*/:&:/
s/:((0:)+)/:<\1>/g
:C
s/0:>/>0:/g
/<0/{s/<>//g
bC
}
s/<>(0:)+/:/
s/<>//g
/^::/!s/://
/::$/!s/:$//
```

I use 22 regular expressions, as sed can't compare numbers or make arrays. For each line of input, sed runs the commands and prints the line. During testing, I put several lines of alleged IP addresses in a file, and fed this file to sed. A reference to extended regular expressions is in [re_format(7)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=re_format&sektion=7&manpath=OpenBSD%20Current&arch=i386&format=html).

1. `s/^/:/` adds an extra colon to the beginning of the line. I use this extra colon to golf the next two commands.
2. `/^(:[0-9A-Fa-f]{0,4})*$/!d` checks if the whole line matches zero or more groups of colons followed by zero to four hexadecimal digits. `!` negates the check, so `d` deletes lines with too big hexadecimal numbers or with invalid characters. When `d` deletes a line, sed runs no more commands on this line.
3. `s/:0*([^:])/:\1/g` deletes leading 0s from each number. It would change `:0000:0000:` to `:0:0:`. I must do this because my contraction loop only works with single-digit 0s.
4. `s/://` deletes the extra colon. It deletes only the first colon.
5. `s/::/:=/` changes the first `::` to `:=`. This is so later commands can match `=` rather than `::`, and so `=` does not count as a colon. If there is no `::`, this substitution safely does nothing.

   - Now `::` must make at least one 0, but there are three different cases for placing this 0.
6. `s/(.:=)(.)/\10:\2/` is the first case. If `::` was between two other characters, then `:=` becomes `:=0:`. This is the only case that adds a colon.
7. `s/^:=/0&/` is the second case. If `::` was at beginning of line, then put 0 there.
8. `s/=$/&0/` is the third case, for `::` at end of line.
9. `:E` is the label for the expansion loop.
10. `/(.*:){7}/!{/=/!d` begins a conditional block if the line has fewer than 7 colons. `/=/!d` deletes lines that had no `::` and not enough colons.
11. `s//=0:/` adds one colon. Empty `//` repeats the last regular expression, so this is really `s/=/=0:/`.
12. `bE` branches to `:E` to continue the loop.
13. `}` closes the block. Now the line has at least seven colons.
14. `s/=//` deletes `=`.
15. `/^:|::|:$|(.*:){8}/d` is a final check after expansion. It deletes lines with a leading colon, an extra `::` that was not expanded, a trailing colon, or eight or more colons.
16. `p` prints the line, which is an IP address in long form.
17. `s/.*/:&:/` wraps the address in extra colons.

    - The next task is to find the longest group of 0s, like `:0:0:0:`, and contract it into `::`.
18. `s/:((0:)+)/:<\1>/g` eats each group of 0s, so `:0:0:0:` would become `:<0:0:0:>`.
19. `:C` is the label for the contraction loop.
20. `s/0:>/>0:/g` moves one 0 from each mouth, so `:<0:0:0:>` would become `:<0:0:>0:`.
21. `/<0/{s/<>//g` opens a conditional block if any mouth is not empty. `s/<>//g` deletes all empty mouths, because those groups are too short.
22. `bC` continues the contraction loop.
23. `}` closes the block. Now any mouth is empty and marks the longest group of 0s.
24. `s/<>(0:)+/:/` contracts the longest group, so `:<>0:0:0:` would become `::`. In a tie, it picks the empty mouth on the left.
25. `s/<>//g` deletes any other empty mouths.
26. `/^::/!s/://` deletes the first extra colon unless it is part of `::`.
27. `/::$/!s/:$//` does so for the last extra colon. Then sed prints the IP address in short form.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3: 387 characters

Even works with improperly shortened input.

```
$ echo '1::2:0:0:0:3' | python3 ipv6.py 
1:0:0:2:0:0:0:3
1:0:0:2::3
```

The double replace of `':::'` with `'::'` feels really bad but not sure how to cleanly deal with the longest string of 0's when it abuts one or both ends.

```
c=':'
p=print
try:
 B=[int(x,16)if x else''for x in input().split(c)];L=len(B)
 if any(B)-1:B=[''];L=1
 if L!=8:s=B.index('');B[s:s+1]=[0]*(9-L)
 for b in B:assert-1<b<2**16
 H=[format(x,'X')for x in B];o=c.join(H);p(o);n=''.join(str(h=='0')[0]for h in H)
 for i in range(8,0,-1):
  s=n.find('T'*i)
  if s>=0:H[s:s+i]=[c*2];p(c.join(H).replace(c*3,c*2).replace(c*3,c*2));q
 p(o)
except:0
```

Replace the final `pass` with `raise` to see how it's <strike>crashing</strike> protecting against malformed input.

```
$ cat ipv6-test.sh 
echo '1080:0:0:0:8:800:200C:417A' | python3 ipv6.py
echo '1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8' | python3 ipv6.py
echo 'FF01::101' | python3 ipv6.py
echo '0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1' | python3 ipv6.py
echo '0:0:0:0:1:0:0:0' | python3 ipv6.py
echo '1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0' | python3 ipv6.py
echo '::' | python3 ipv6.py
echo '1:0:0:2:0:0:0:3' | python3 ipv6.py
echo '1::2:0:0:0:3' | python3 ipv6.py
echo '1:0:0:8:8:0:0:3' | python3 ipv6.py
echo 'ABCD:1234' | python3 ipv6.py
echo 'ABCDE::1234' | python3 ipv6.py
echo '1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9' | python3 ipv6.py
echo ':::1' | python3 ipv6.py
echo 'codegolf puzzle' | python3 ipv6.py
$ ./ipv6-test.sh 
1080:0:0:0:8:800:200C:417A
1080::8:800:200C:417A

1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8
1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8

FF01:0:0:0:0:0:0:101
FF01::101

0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
::1

0:0:0:0:1:0:0:0
::1:0:0:0

1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0
1::


0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0
::

1:0:0:2:0:0:0:3
1:0:0:2::3

1:0:0:2:0:0:0:3
1:0:0:2::3

1:0:0:8:8:0:0:3
1::8:8:0:0:3
```

Comment: @DigitalTrauma corrected.  I was searching for "0:0:0..." and it was capturing trailing 0's

Comment: You really don't hear the word "abuts" enough nowadays

Comment: A bug? This program accepted `1:2:3:4::a:b:c:d` but rejected both `::2:3:4:a:b:c:d` and `1:2:3:4:a:b:c::`. I believe it was wrong all three times.